# navigator.credentials.create() times out in electron

Tags: authentication, electron, public-key-encryption, webauthn

After scouring the web for an answer to this question, it's still unclear to me whether electron supports authenticating users via public key credentials and the WebAuthn specification.

Since v4+ (Chromium 69), electron has had support for both `navigator.credentials` API and the `PublicKeyCredential` interface. However, attempting to create a new credential using `navigator.credentials.create()` results in the request timing out (if `PublicKeyCredentialCreationOptions.timeout` is set). Additionally, `PublicKeyCredential.isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable()` resolves to `false` which indicates that platform authenticators such as Windows Hello and TouchID are *not* supported in electron.

In Chrome and other supported browsers, the call to `navigator.credentials.create()` results in an authorization prompt where the user can enter their security key (eg. biometric scanner or physical usb device). Has anyone had success in implementing similar behaviour an electron app?

Comment: Cross-platform authenticators (eg. usb key) seem to be working on Windows (at least the prompt is displayed). I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/27355) with electron.